# How to animate the repositioning of divs when a new element is added

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate an imessage like text app. When a message is sent, I create a new element in js, add textContent and append the child div to a parent div. When a new div is added, I want the current divs to smoothly slide up to make room for the new message. Currently, the other text bubble divs just reposition themselves in an abrupt manner.

Append new message into messages div:

```
var myMessage = document.createElement("div");
    myMessage.className = "myMessage";
    myMessage.id = "message";
    myMessage.textContent = input.value;
    messages.appendChild(myMessage);
```

I have tried to add to implement css animation by adding a class to messages (parent div) on new message: `messages.classList.add("pushUp");` but this does not create the smooth effect I want. When the animation is called, it correctly pushes up all the messages. However, this also pushes up the newest message. I attempted to only add class `pushUp` to the last text bubble div above the newest div and change the margin-bottom in the pushUp animation, however instead of pushing up all messages except for the newest, this method pushes the newest message down. Frankly, I don't think a css animation is the answer to my problem. Is there something like the transition style that will animate the adding and repositioning of divs? If not, I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a simple slide animation with `scroll-behavior: smooth;`. After spending so much time on this its sort of a slap on the face that this is the answer to the problem but am still happy I was able to find the problem. Hope this helps anyone else trying to complete something similar in the future.